# Using the Linux Fault Injection framework

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, code-injection, fault

I'm trying to use the Linux fault injection framework to inject page allocation faults. I'm trying to use the `failcmd.sh` script provided with the Linux kernel in `tools/testing/fault-injection/`.

After setting variable `FAILCMD_TYPE` to `fail_page_alloc`, I'm running the following command:

```
./failcmd.sh --times=-1 --interval=1 --verbose=2 <program_to_be_run_with_fi>.
```

All programs I have tried this with have run fine and I do not get any debug information back although I set verbose to 2. I'm using kernel 3.2.0-32 on Ubuntu 12.04.1.

Does anyone have experience with fault injection in Linux?

Comment: Did you configure the kernel with `fault-injection` enabled?  It won't work without kernel support.  You cann't use a stock Linux kernel.

Comment: Have you tried asking your question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?